# Two applications accessing GPS at the same time

Tags: android, gps

I have two different Android applications. One of them is accessing the GPS of the mobile phone at an  instant of time. Is it possible that my second application can concurrently access the GPS?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, multiple Android applications can make use of the LocationManager and GPS hardware at the same time.

Comment: is there anything special that has to be done on the app for this to work?

Comment: Nope... Accessing the GPS is abstracted by the OS.